# Angular 5 upload cropped file to PHP backend

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular5, httpclient

I have the below functions that lets the user take a photo with the camera, or select it from the gallery, then crops the image, then I need to upload it to a server, using POST and multipart/form-data
I have used tons of upload methods, but none of them seem to work.

```
public async takePicture(sourceType) {

    // Create options for the Camera Dialog
    const options = {
        quality: 100,
        sourceType: sourceType,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true,
    };

    try {
        // Get the data of an image
        const imagePath = await this.camera.getPicture(options);

        // Special handling for Android library
        let uploadedImage;
        if (this.platform.is("android") && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
            const filePath = await this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath);
            const correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            const currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf("?"));
            uploadedImage = await this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
        } else {
            const currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            const correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            uploadedImage = await this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
        }

        console.log('PATH', cordova.file.dataDirectory + uploadedImage);
        this.crop.crop(cordova.file.dataDirectory + uploadedImage, {quality: 75}).then(
            newImage => {
                this.uploadedImage = newImage.replace("file://", "");

                // UPLOAD HERE
            },
            error => {
                this.presentToast("Error while selecting image.");
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        this.presentToast("Error while selecting image.");
    }
}


public async copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName): Promise<string> {
    const externalStoragePath: string = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    try {
        const entry = await this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(namePath + currentName);
        const dirEntry: any = await this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(externalStoragePath);

        entry.copyTo(dirEntry, newFileName, () => { }, () => {
            this.presentToast("Error while storing file.");
        });

        return newFileName;
    } catch (error) {
        this.presentToast("Error while storing file.");
    }
}
```

I have the file in a path like file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1FF313F5-5736-44D0-968D- 37889E3ED537/Library/NoCloud/1536106729187.jpg OR /var/mobile/.../tmp/something.jpg

I have tried uploading them with:

```
const options = {} as any; // Set any options you like
const formData = new FormData();

// Append files to the virtual form.
const file = new File();
formData.append("fsFile", this.uploadedImage, "yes");

// Send it.
this.httpClient.post("/files/upload_tmp", formData, options)
                    .toPromise()
                    .catch((e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
```

But formData expects a blob, not a path, so this does not work. Can I use the path to make the upload, or how do I convert it to a blob ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cordova recommends to use https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/ for transfering files from the phone to a server. It's due to cross-platform support and some tweaks to get things working correctly.

There you got "FileUploadOptions", in which you put your path of the file (local path on the device) into the options.

Example:

```
// !! Assumes variable uploadedImage contains a valid URL to a text file on the device,
//    for example, cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file.txt
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = uploadedImage.substr(uploadedImage.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "text/plain";

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(uploadedImage, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), SUCCESS_FUNCTION, ERROR_FUNCTION, options)
```

Comment: as far as I know, this is deprecated .. I don't really want to use something that is deprecated